# Network utilization column in windows 8 task manager not working

Tags: windows-8, task-manager

Network utilization column in windows 8 task manager not working; It always reporting 0% although it reports values for each app!

[image: Screenshoot]

Comment: Try stressing the network connection harder. Without being able to tell how you have it sorted, if Chrome is the only program using the network right then, 0.1Mbps might not hit 1% or higher utilization. Start up something that uses more bandwidth and then see if it changes.

Comment: I tried this but noway.
It was working but it stopped suddenly !

Comment: @Mark 0.1Mbps must be reflected as 0.1%; It was working; Was Microsoft reduced the accuracy in any update?

Comment: I don't know, sorry. Maybe check your event log and see if there are any complaints about loading performance counters for the network card.

Comment: Did you find anything about it? I have the same problem but can't find the error.

Comment: @ineentho Yes, Microsoft has reduced the sensitivity from floating point to integer i.e. the minimum value is 1%.

Comment: I had the same and the reason was that it was monitoring the virtual network adapter installed by VirtualBox